# BIRT Report, SQL

Tags: sql, birt

I am new to BIRT, and I guess my question is very easy, but I can’t see how to accomplish my objective…

The task is to create a report for different courts on their requests containing different information about courts’ employees. `DataSetRow[“COURT”]` represents the heading of the report and it changes according to employees’ courts, usually it changes its title alphabetically, it depends on results I get and a court which requests that information. I need to make it dependent on a USER who needs the report. For this purpose I need PERSONAL_ID columns from `USER_ID` and `HR` to match and therefore `DataSetRow[“COURT”]` should become the same number which COURT column has. I have no idea how to define this for a USER…

Report Parameters:
**DATA_FORM**,
**USER_ID**

There are two important tables in the database:

**USERS**: which contains USER_ID column and PERSONAL_ID column.

And **HR**: The same PERSONAL_ID and C_COURT, which I need.

```
SELECT   

H.PERSONAL_ID,
SURNAME||' '||NAME||' '||SNAME AS NAME,
DECODE_UNI (H.T_COURT, H.C_COURT) AS COURT,
DECODE_UNI (HA.T_COURT, HA.C_COURT) AS C_COURT,
TO_CHAR (TO_DATE(BIRTH_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'),'yyyy') AS BIRTH_DATE,
DECODE_UNI (HA.T_POSITION, HA.C_POSITION) AS POSITION,
DECODE_UNI (HA.T_DEPARTMENT, HA.C_DEPARTMENT) AS DEPARTMENT,
DECODE_UNI (HW.T_AWARD_TYPE, HW.C_AWARD_TYPE) AS AWARD_TYPE,
TO_CHAR (HW.AWARD_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') AS AWARD_DATE,
HW.AWARD_DESC,
U.PERSONAL_ID AS PERSONAL_USER

FROM

HR H, HR_APPOINTMENT HA, HR_AWARD HW, USERS U

WHERE

H.PERSONAL_ID = HA.PERSONAL_ID
AND H.PERSONAL_ID = HW.PERSONAL_ID
AND HA.ACTIVE = 1
AND H.C_STATE = 1
AND HA.STATUS_LAST = 1
AND H.REC_DATE <= TO_DATE (?, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND USER_ID = ?
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to answer without having the whole picture, but as you described the case it seems a join is missing in the query:

```
AND H.PERSONAL_ID=U.PERSONAL_ID
```

Comment: Thank you, I have figured this out: I simply created two DataSets.